# How to install Solaris 11 on Sparc Enterprise T5240 from HyperTerminal

Tags: solaris, system-installation

We received one Sparc T5240 Server and this is the first time experience with Sparc Servers. I never even saw them before. So i connected to Server using Cutecom app an alternative for Ubuntu to Windows Hyperterminal.

I insert the Solaris 11 Boot Media and cutecom generated this log during this process

```
0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\
0:0:0>SPARC(R) Enterprise T5140/T5240 POST 4.30.4 2009/08/19 07:50 
       /export/delivery/delivery/4.30/4.30.4/post4.30.4-micro/Niagara/maramba/integrated  (root)  
\0xa5\0x9d\0xa1\0xd1 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved
0:0:0>POST enabling CMP 0 threads: 00000000.ffffffff
&\0xa2\0xa1\0xc9\0x95\0x85\0x91\0xcd: 000000ff.00ffffff
0:0:0>VBSC mode is: 00000000.00000001
0:0:0>VBSC level is: 00000000.00000001
\0x9d Normal mode, MAX Testing.
0:0:0>VBSC setting verbosity level 2
0:0:0>Test Memory.....\0x08\\0x08|\0x08/\0x08-\0x08\\0x08|\0x08\0x08Done
0:0:0>Setup POST Mailbox .....\0x08-\0x08\\0x08|-\0x08\\0x08|\0x08/\0x08-\0x08Done
\0x15\0xcd\0xd1\0x95\0xc9 CPU Tests Basic.....0:0:0>Init MMU.....
0:0:0>L2 Tests.....Done
0:0:0>Extended CPU Tests.....
0:0:0>Scrub Memory..... CPU Tests.....Done
0:0:0>Extended Memory Tests.....Done
0:0:0>SPU CWQ Tests... Done
0:0:0>MAU Tests... Done
0:0:0>NCU Setup and PIU link train
0:0:0>NEPTUNE Network Interface Unit Tests.....
2014-04-19 13:24:55.129 0:0:0>\0x09POST Passed all devices.
2014-04-19 13:24:55.134 0:0:0>POST:\0x09Return to VBSC.
2014-04-19 13:24:55.138 0:0:0>Master set ACK for vbsc runpost command and spin...
 addr:0x1d - link is down
*****************************************************************************

*

* Starting Desktop Login on display :0...

*

* Wait for the Desktop Login screen before logging in.

*

*****************************************************************************





*****************************************************************************

*

* The X-server can not be started on display :0...

*

* See file /var/dt/Xerrors for details.

*

*****************************************************************************
```

I need to Install OS but everytime it reach X-server line and stuck.

Answer (score 2):

That log shows that it is booting Solaris 10 off the existing hard disk, not the Solaris 11 boot media.   (The *Starting Desktop Login on display :0...* message comes from the old CDE login manager, which isn't included in Solaris 11.)

Make sure you’ve told the system to boot off the cdrom, not the disk, normally by entering `boot cdrom` at the **`ok`** prompt:

- [Perform a Normal System Initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19712-01/E21412-01/z40001341020650.html)
- [Boot the Solaris Operating System](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19712-01/E21412-01/z40001341020700.html)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting system CPU console messages alright. I don't see any ILOM (Integrated Lights Out Manager [service processor]) messages. Here's the [T5240 Getting Started Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19910-01/820-3521-11/820-3521-11.pdf). I would try:

```
#.
reset -force /SYS
start /SP/console
boot cdrom
```

Which does:

1. #. => Break out to the ILOM console.
2. reset -force /SYS => Force the system CPU to the boot prompt ("ok" prompt).
3. start /SP/console => Restart the  connection to the system CPU console. (Hit return. You should see the "ok" prompt.)
4. boot cdrom => Start loading Solaris 11 from DVD.

If you can deal with the fact that it's a big Java-based app running in your browser, then I recommend you learn about the web-based ILOM interface. It lets you access the system CPU console (keyboard and video buffer) remotely.

Here's a pointer to the [T5240 doc set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19712-01/E21412-01/z40003409112.html).

Comment: Thanks Dear. I will try this on coming Saturday because as of now I dont have access to Server right now. I will comeback to you soon

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /HOST/console
set /HOST/bootmode script="setenv auto-boot? false"
reset /SYS


start /SP/console


show-disks

#search path of disk

boot $PATH:f

example:

boot /pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/usb@1,2/storage@2/disk:f
```

Comment: Hello, welcome on the Unix SE! Your answers seems so, like code snippet. Please try to give meaningful, textual answers.